# How exactly should I run distributed training with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing

I have 2 computers. How can I run distributed training on them and see it converges 2 times faster? I got ["distributed example"](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/keras), but this "example" contains no word about computers setup. I got some words about [setting `TF_CONFIG`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#TF_CONFIG), but again, it is highly unclear, what both computers should do. I can't run the same script on both computers. I expect one computer should wait another computer to send batches to it, but I don't see any clues, how to prepare it for this...

I wrote on one computer (`calculon`)

```
os.environ["TF_CONFIG"] = json.dumps({
    "cluster": {
        "worker": ["calculon:2222", "lagrangian:2222"]
    },
   "task": {"type": "chief", "index": 0}
})
```

and on another computer (`lagrangian`)

```
os.environ["TF_CONFIG"] = json.dumps({
    "cluster": {
        "worker": ["calculon:2222", "lagrangian:2222"]
    },
   "task": {"type": "worker", "index": 1}
})
```

Should I open port `2222` on both computers? At which moment the sctript will start to listen to this port? Which line in ["distributed example"](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/keras) starts listening?